# Using com.spotify, how to set the image version

Tags: java, maven, docker

Using the com.spotify plugin to Maven to automate the building of Docker images, how does one set the version image?

It appears to, by default, use the Maven version. I can also use `<useGitCommitId>` to make it the git commit short hash, instead. However, if I wanted it to be a combination of these things, or something else, entirely, how would that be accomplished?

Comment: Can you add you pom file config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set the image tags as such:

```
  <configuration>
    ...
    <imageTags>
       <imageTag>${project.version}</imageTag>
       <imageTag>latest</imageTag>
    </imageTags>
  </configuration>
```